# Langchain pinecone similarity search error : Invalid type for variable 'namespace'

Tags: python, callback, langchain, pinecone

I'm trying to getting work similarity search with Pincone's existing index. But I'm getting following error when passing the query. This is only happening on local machine. everything working fine in colab.

```
pinecone.core.client.exceptions.ApiTypeError: Invalid type for variable 'namespace'. Required value type is str and passed type was NoneType at ['namespace']
```

My implementation is like follows.

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
    openai_api_key=openai_api_key,
    model=embedding_model,
)

pinecone.init(
api_key=os.getenv("pineconeapikey"),  # find at app.pinecone.io
environment=os.getenv("pineconeenvironment"),  # next to api key in console



def data(query):
    """ Ansewer product related questions. Function requires use query"""
    docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)
    answer = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
    return answer
```

Comment: need to see how the embedding was added to `pinecone` in the first place. add minimal code that we can run and reproduce this error. I added a new index and then when I ran similarity on it, it worked okay for me. So need more detail to reproduce your error.

Comment: Everything is working fine on Colab. But the Issue was only on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with python environment. I was able to run correctly on a new python environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because you don't have defined `index_name`, and `docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index` expects a string. to do so, instantiate `Index` with `index_name`.

Try this:

```
def data(query):
    """ Answer product related questions. Function requires use query"""
    index_name = pinecone.Index("<the-name-of-your-namespace>") #Add this line
    docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)
    answer = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
    return answer
```

Here's LangChain's [documentation on Pinecone](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.pinecone.Pinecone.html?highlight=pinecone#).

Comment: i think index is fed to the call, otherwise would have received the error `PineconeProtocolError: Failed to connect; did you specify the correct index name?`